# Looping 3 WordPress articles in a carousel container

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming, slick.js

I am currently using Slick Carousel to rotate through articles on my website homepage.

This currently works by using the following code:

```
 <div class="news-slider">

        <?php $i = 0; ?>

        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=8,7,9&posts_per_page=6' ); ?>

        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

        <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

        <?php if ( $i % 2 ==  0) : ?>
          <div class="wrap">
        <?php endif; ?>

          <div class="news-snippet">
            <div class="news-snippet-thumbnail" style="background: url('<?php echo $edTheDev = $backgroundImg[0] ? $backgroundImg[0] : '/wp-content/themes/quantinsight/assets/img/post-thumb.png'; ?>') no-repeat center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>

            <div class="news-snippet-content">
              <h3 class="[ f-avenir-book-26 u-ColorBlue ]"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

              <p class="news-snippet-date"><?php echo the_time('d.m.y'); ?></p>

              <p class=""><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>


        <?php if ( $i % 2 != 0 ) : ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        $i++;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
      </div>
```

Instead of display 2 articles inside a carousel wrap I now want to display 3 articles.

I thought if I changed $i % 2 to $i % 3 that this would update the articles displayed in each wrap but this breaks the carousel completely.

Any suggestions on I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: it won't work with modulo % like this. This is a technique to open the wrapper div and close it after printing exactly 2 elements in an alternating fashion:

```
$i:
 0: open, element 1
 1: element 2, close
 2: open,  element 3,
 3: element 4, close
```

For % 3, it will produce this:

```
$i:
 0: open, element 1
 1: element 2, close
 2: element 3, close
 3: open, element 4
 4: element 5, close
 5: element 6, close
```

Thus, there will be twice as much closing than opening `<div>` tags.

To fix this, you have to change the `if`-conditions like so:

```
 <div class="news-slider">

        <?php
        $i = 0;
        $numItems = 3; // Change the number of items per slide here 
        ?>

        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=8,7,9&posts_per_page=6' ); ?>

        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

        <?php $backgroundImg = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>

        <?php if ( $i % $numItems ==  0) : ?>
          <div class="wrap">
        <?php endif; ?>

          <div class="news-snippet">
            <div class="news-snippet-thumbnail" style="background: url('<?php echo $edTheDev = $backgroundImg[0] ? $backgroundImg[0] : '/wp-content/themes/quantinsight/assets/img/post-thumb.png'; ?>') no-repeat center; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;"></div>

            <div class="news-snippet-content">
              <h3 class="[ f-avenir-book-26 u-ColorBlue ]"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

              <p class="news-snippet-date"><?php echo the_time('d.m.y'); ?></p>

              <p class=""><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">Read More</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>


        <?php if ( ($i + 1) % $numItems == 0 ) : ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        $i++;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
      </div>
```

This works by changing the wrap-closing if-condition so it fires after exactly each `$numItem` iterations after the opening. You can configure `$numItems` to any positive number of items you want.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for your answer and explanation!